# WordPress : Issue with wp_query and gd star rating plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have used GD Star Rating plugin with my Wordpress installation, for creating 2 different sets of Ratings (Posts and Videos). *(I was not able to find any other plugin that supports this feature).*

I have used following arguments in one wp_query to display a list of top rated videos, and it's working fine.

```
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'youtube_videos',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'gdsr_sort' => 'rating',
    'gdsr_multi' => 3
);
```

On the same page, i am trying to show a list of top rated posts, with following arguments in wp_query, but it's not working.

```
$args=array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'gdsr_sort' => 'rating',
    'gdsr_multi' => 0
);
```

I found that issue is with value passes in 'gdsr_multi' varibale, if i remove this variable from the top rated videos 2nd part of code works fine.

I am not being able to run both together, any suggestions please?

---

For `gdsr_multi` variable documentation of GD Star rating plugin says:

- For standard rating data, don't use this variable, or set it to zero.
- To get multi ratings data this variable must be set to multi set id to use.

Comment: have you checked answers?

Answer (score 0):

You should reset your query before start a new one. `wp_reset_query();` will destroys the previous query used on a custom Loop. This function should be called after The Loop to ensure conditional tags work as expected. As example:

```
<?php
    query_posts( 'post_parent=5' );
    if ( have_posts() ) :
       while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
       ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a><br /><?php
       endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
   //your second query will be here.
?>
```

For more details, you can check [Wordpress official codex: wp reset query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query)

Comment: I have already used wp_reset_query(); it did not worked fot gdsr_multi  variable.

Comment: Also i have used $my_query = null; and then $my_query = new WP_Query($args); to remove previous query, but no change :(

Comment: are you using custom query?

Comment: i have used $my_query = new WP_Query($args); here $args is an array, which i posted in my question above.